# Calculation of coordinates of the intersection point of several circles

Tags: c#, geolocation

Condition is: I am doing the parsing of one site with three geoposition (with known locations), in response json sends me distance to the object in kilometers.

Actually the problem: It is necessary to calculate the geographical coordinates of the search object, albeit with minor errors (for displaying on the map).

Help is needed in formulating a mathematical function (including the calculation error) or immediately algorithm C# :)

Comment: http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/determine-where-two-circles-intersect-in-c/

Comment: No, such a decision does not provide accounting errors. And I need to use at least 3 of the circle